# Where can I ask this question about unix & java?

Tags: support, specific-question, site-recommendation

There is programmers.stackexchange.com, unix.stackexchange.com and stackoverflow.com

I have a question to ask about unix and java.

> #### Is quartz scheduler better than crontab?
>
> Quartz Scheduler can figure out when day-light savings changed where as crontab can't do that. We have to manually change the timings in the crontab.

Where can I ask this question?

Comment: See [Gorilla Vs. Shark.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/)

Comment: There's probably a decent question about crontab hidden in there, something along the lines of "How do I do *foo* using `crontab`?"  You'd need to be specific about what *foo* is (running a job every 24 hours regardless of DST, or something else?).

Comment: Thanks for not down-voting my question, rather, help me understand how to phrase my question.

Comment: Regarding downvotes, [please read the FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

None. “Is X better than Y?” is [rarely a good question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/). If you have a specific task in mind, it's fine to ask for a method to accomplish it, but it's best to leave your options open (what if the best solution is neither Quartz Scheduler nor Cron?).

Furthermore, you seem to answer your own question: you like Quartz Scheduler better for its DST handling (indeed, Cron only supports schedules in the system local time). So what are you asking?

If you have a valid question about Cron or Quartz Scheduler or scheduling a task on a unix system in general, you can ask on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). This is a system administration task, not a programming question. If you had a programming question, on unix or otherwise, [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) would be the right place (U&L doesn't take programming questions).

Answer (score 4):

As it's written, it wouldn't be a good fit for any StackExchange site. It would be closed as "not constructive", which is defined as

> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

"Is X better than Y?" questions are rarely objective, and typically attract supporters of both. While it could generate a useful discussion, discussion is not the purpose of SE sites.